# LFS 7.10 - why am I getting an error when using make command for expect-5.45

Tags: c++, c, linux, gcc, lfs

I am trying to compile expect-5.45 for LFS everything works until I use the make command, below is the output of using the make command:

```
gcc -DPACKAGE_NAME=\"expect\" -DPACKAGE_TARNAME=\"expect\" -DPACKAGE_VERSION=\"5.45\" -DPACKAGE_STRING=\"expect\ 5.45\" -DPACKAGE_BUGREPORT=\"\" -DBUILD_expect= -DSTDC_HEADERS=1 -DHAVE_SYS_TYPES_H=1 -DHAVE_SYS_STAT_H=1 -DHAVE_STDLIB_H=1 -DHAVE_STRING_H=1 -DHAVE_MEMORY_H=1 -DHAVE_STRINGS_H=1 -DHAVE_INTTYPES_H=1 -DHAVE_STDINT_H=1 -DHAVE_UNISTD_H=1 -DHAVE_LIMITS_H=1 -DHAVE_SYS_PARAM_H=1 -DUSE_THREAD_ALLOC=1 -D_REENTRANT=1 -D_THREAD_SAFE=1 -DTCL_THREADS=1 -DMODULE_SCOPE=extern\ __attribute__\(\(__visibility__\(\"hidden\"\)\)\) -D_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE=1 -DTCL_WIDE_INT_IS_LONG=1 -DUSE_TCL_STUBS=1 -DUSE_TCL_STUBS=1 -DHAVE_SYS_SELECT_H=1 -DHAVE_SYSMACROS_H=1 -DHAVE_STROPTS_H=1 -DHAVE_SYS_FCNTL_H=1 -DRETSIGTYPE=void -DHAVE_SYS_TIME_H=1 -DTIME_WITH_SYS_TIME=1 -DHAVE_STRUCT_TM_TM_ZONE=1 -DHAVE_TM_ZONE=1 -DHAVE_GMTIME_R=1 -DHAVE_LOCALTIME_R=1 -DHAVE_TM_GMTOFF=1 -DHAVE_TIMEZONE_VAR=1 -DHAVE_OPENPTY=1 -DHAVE_MEMMOVE=1 -DHAVE_SYSCONF=1 -DHAVE_STRFTIME=1 -DHAVE_STRCHR=1 -DHAVE_TIMEZONE=1 -DHAVE_SIGLONGJMP=1 -DHAVE_MEMCPY=1 -DWNOHANG_BACKUP_VALUE=1 -DSELECT_MASK_TYPE=fd_set -DHAVE_PTMX=1 -DHAVE_TCSETATTR=1 -DPOSIX=1 -DHAVE_TERMIO=1 -DHAVE_TERMIOS=1 -DSETPGRP_VOID=1 -DHAVE_SV_TIMEZONE=1 -DHAVE_LONG_FILE_NAMES=1  -DTCL_DEBUGGER -DUSE_NON_CONST -DSCRIPTDIR=\"/tools/lib/expect5.45\" -DEXECSCRIPTDIR=\"/tools/lib/expect5.45\" -DSTTY_BIN=\"/bin/stty\" -DDFLT_STTY="\"sane\"" -I. -I"." -I"/tools/include"    -pipe -O2 -fomit-frame-pointer -Wall -fPIC  -c `echo exp_command.c` -o exp_command.o
In file included from exp_command.c:72:0:
exp_command.h:132:22: error: field 'wait' has incomplete type
     WAIT_STATUS_TYPE wait; /* raw status from wait() */
                      ^
In file included from /tools/include/tclPort.h:23:0,
                 from /tools/include/tclInt.h:36,
                 from exp_command.c:61:
exp_command.c: In function 'exp_wait_zero':
/tools/include/tclUnixPort.h:228:29: error: invalid application of 'sizeof' to incomplete type 'union wait'
 #   define WAIT_STATUS_TYPE union wait
                             ^
exp_command.c:256:23: note: in expansion of macro 'WAIT_STATUS_TYPE'
     for (i=0;i<sizeof(WAIT_STATUS_TYPE);i++) {
                       ^
exp_command.c: In function 'Exp_SpawnObjCmd':
exp_command.c:587:9: warning: unused variable 'ttyfd' [-Wunused-variable]
     int ttyfd;
         ^
exp_command.c: At top level:
exp_command.c:2803:22: error: field 'wait_status' has incomplete type
     WAIT_STATUS_TYPE wait_status;
                      ^
exp_command.c: In function 'Exp_DisconnectObjCmd':
exp_command.c:3120:9: warning: unused variable 'ttyfd' [-Wunused-variable]
     int ttyfd;
         ^
exp_command.c: At top level:
exp_command.c:537:1: warning: 'expSetpgrp' defined but not used [-Wunused-function]
 expSetpgrp()
 ^
exp_command.c: In function 'Exp_SpawnObjCmd':
exp_command.c:1353:5: warning: ignoring return value of 'write', declared with attribute warn_unused_result [-Wunused-result]
     write(status_pipe[1], &errno, sizeof errno);
     ^
Makefile:318: recipe for target 'exp_command.o' failed
make: *** [exp_command.o] Error 1
```

To configure I am using:

```
./configure --prefix=/tools \
--with-tcl=/tools/lib \
--with-tclinclude=/tools/include
```

There was also no log file metioned

Comment: what do you mean "fulfill all dependencies"

Comment: Did you install exactly the packages the book told you? The exact version?

Comment: Have a recent enough gcc and such, but I may even be wrong to begin with.

Comment: I did copy the commands exactly as the book showed me

Comment: I have the very same problem - and I have an up-to-date system.

Comment: @shevy Had any luck?